# equivalent of objdump for dex files

Tags: dex, objdump

- Is there any equivalent to `objdump` for `dex` files?
- I don't want to decompile them, just be able to watch their content

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps someone in the future:

```
$ sudo apt install dexdump
```

Answer (score 0):

baksmali has a `dump` command that generates an annotated hex dump of a dex file

```
baksmali dump helloworld.dex > helloworld.txt
```

```
                           |-----------------------------
                           |code_item section
                           |-----------------------------
                           |
                           |[0] code_item: LHelloWorld;->main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
0001c4: 0200               |  registers_size = 2
0001c6: 0100               |  ins_size = 1
0001c8: 0200               |  outs_size = 2
0001ca: 0000               |  tries_size = 0
0001cc: 0000 0000          |  debug_info_off = 0x0
0001d0: 0800 0000          |  insns_size = 0x8
                           |  instructions:
0001d4: 6200 0000          |    sget-object v0, Ljava/lang/System;->out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
0001d8: 1a01 0000          |    const-string v1, "Hello World!"
0001dc: 6e20 0100 1000     |    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Ljava/io/PrintStream;->println(Ljava/lang/String;)V
0001e2: 0e00               |    return-void
```

It is also able to list the items in some of the various constant pools

```
baksmali list classes helloworld.dex
```

```
LHelloWorld;
```

---

```
baksmali list methods helloworld.dex
```

```
LHelloWorld;->main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
Ljava/io/PrintStream;->println(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

---

```
baksmali list fields helloworld.dex
```

```
Ljava/lang/System;->out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
```

---

```
baksmali list strings helloworld.dex
```

```
"Hello World!"
"LHelloWorld;"
"Ljava/io/PrintStream;"
"Ljava/lang/Object;"
"Ljava/lang/String;"
"Ljava/lang/System;"
"V"
"VL"
"[Ljava/lang/String;"
"main"
"out"
"println"
```